# Ionic v3 problems with npm (typescript) plugins after oficial migration to v4

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

Ionic Team finally changed v4 version as an official (To see docs to v3 we need to click https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/ but I think there is a problem with support for typescript for native plugins.

Eg. When I want to install some plugin and run `npm install --save @ionic-native/MY_NEW_PLUGIN` it downloads the newest version, but this version is not supported by v3 (and I need to find e.g. version from 2 months elier to make it work) It looks like Ionic did not changed documentation for v3 after migration?

Can anyone confirm? Do we need to wait for update or run it another way, cause I do not want to migrate to the v4 now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, finally Ionic team added versions to npm install `@4` in documentation to `@Ionic v3`

Sample: `npm install --save @ionic-native/camera@4`

Answer (score 0):

used /ngx in end of line of import it will works like

```
import { StatusBar } from ‘@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx’;
```

or you can try to find Second last Version of Puglin and Append while adding Plugin like

```
npm install @ionic-native/native-storage@4.19.0
```

Here.. Lastest Version is 5.0.0. Don't Make Assumption Based On Number Go in Repo or npm link

Comment: Yes, when I downloaded earlier version like @4.19.0 it works but there are some plugins that have versions 5.1.0, 5.1.2, ... and If I only chose second last it may still not work so thats why I took version from 2 months. 

But still I think this is not good idea to do this by hand. 
I will check the ngx option

Comment: check ngx option and kindly upvote if your earlier version works :)